# Mocking a neo4j Record instance in a Unittest

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, neo4j, instance

I have a method:

```
def retrieve_datetime_and_device(self, response):
    node_dict = response[0][0]._properties
    dt = node_dict.get("datetime")
    device = node_dict.get("name")

    return dt, device
```

The response is a return from a neo4j query. I'd like to write a unittest for this, however I am unsure how to test when the input for the method requires a Record instance

A typical Record looks like:

```
response = [<Record n=<Node id=902350 labels=frozenset({'DEvice1'}) properties={'name': 'myname', 'Src': 'Somewhere', 'Filename': 'test.xlsx', 'datetime': '2021-02-04 15:14:37'}>>]
```

How can I test this?